# .js file not importing into Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to import countdown.js into my Angular project, but the function is not defined in my countdown-timer.ts file.

- I did npm i countdown --save
- I tried adding the script path in angular.json

ERROR:  `ERROR TypeError: "_node_modules_countdown_countdown_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10___default.a.countdown is not a function""`

countdown-timer.ts

```
import countdown from 'countdown';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-countdown',
  templateUrl: './countdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./countdown.component.css']

})
export class CountdownTimerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log("COUNTDOWN: " + countdown.countdown(new Date(2000, 0, 1)).toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. It should be something like `import countdown from '../../../node_modules/countdown/countdown.js';` the `declare const` will never work. Also, get rid of the script tag that loads the same file, that makes no sense either.

Comment: It also doesn't belong in the angular.json scripts section. Not if you import it.

Comment: I updated the code above. Added the new error I'm getting too. I got rid of script src and angular.json script. Just importing it into .ts like you were saying

Comment: If you're using webpack, you should not be reaching into a crazy filepath deep inside `node_modules` - import directly, using `import countdown from "countdown"`.

Comment: OK, but you still should get rid of the declare. In your `tsconfig.json` set `"esModuleInterop": true` under compilerOptions. And @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is right, it should just be `import countdown from 'countdown';` (and that's not just a webpack thing)

Comment: @user6680 now I see the error. you are using `countdown.countdown(...)` it is just `countdown(...)`

Comment: got rid of declare, updated tsconfig and countdown path. Still getting error above

Comment: See my last comment, you have `countdown.countdown(...)` which again makes no sense.

Comment: It's working! Thanks Aluan Haddad

Comment: That was from the declare I was using.

Comment: That was part of it. Checkout the documentation for the library next time.